# Extend index on business day range

Tags: python, date, pandas, indexing

I have a set of Data points some of which share the same date index

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Date':["2016-01-08","2016-01-15", "2016-01-15", "2016-01-23"], 
'Set': ["1", "2", "3", "4"]})

df
Out[2]: 
         Date Set
0  2016-01-08   1
1  2016-01-15   2
2  2016-01-15   3
3  2016-01-23   4
```

how can I achieve to obtain a pandas data frame that has the business days of a specified period as index (here say January 2016) and the numbers from the df aligned to it?

```
df_out
Out[3]: 
             Set
2016-01-04   NaN
2016-01-05   NaN
2016-01-06   NaN
2016-01-07   NaN 
2016-01-08   1
2016-01-11   NaN
2016-01-12   NaN
2016-01-13   NaN
2016-01-14   NaN 
2016-01-15   2 
2016-01-15   3 
2016-01-18   NaN
2016-01-19   NaN
2016-01-20   NaN
2016-01-21   NaN
2016-01-22   NaN
2016-01-25   NaN
2016-01-26   NaN
2016-01-27   NaN
2016-01-28   NaN
2016-01-29   NaN
```

Comment: I've been working on a solution, but actually I didn't find a way to handle your duplicate index. Take a look at my answer, hope that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're working on the `DatetimeIndex` I build your example using a `Series` rather than a `DataFrame`:

```
s = pd.Series({"2016-01-08":1,      
               "2016-01-15":2,
               "2016-01-16":3,
               "2016-01-23":3})
```

Then I would assign the datetime index:

```
s.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(s.index)
```

Then I build the new index of business days only with:

```
bd = pd.bdate_range('2016-01-01', '2016-01-31')
```

and reindex back the original Series:

```
s = s.reindex(bd)
```

This returns:

```
2016-01-01   NaN
2016-01-04   NaN
2016-01-05   NaN
2016-01-06   NaN
2016-01-07   NaN
2016-01-08     1
2016-01-11   NaN
2016-01-12   NaN
2016-01-13   NaN
2016-01-14   NaN
2016-01-15     2
2016-01-18   NaN
2016-01-19   NaN
2016-01-20   NaN
2016-01-21   NaN
2016-01-22   NaN
2016-01-25   NaN
2016-01-26   NaN
2016-01-27   NaN
2016-01-28   NaN
2016-01-29   NaN
Freq: B, dtype: float64
```

This does not handle the problem of the duplicate index, but hope that helps.

Comment: Fabio, that helps indeed. Thank you very much for your time! The duplicated index .... hmm.... I will try to find a work around.